# Oracle to Postgres connection

Tags: airflow

I have created the Dag and trying to run it. It’s giving below error.

ERROR - Failed to execute job 168054 for task data_transfer (DPY-3015: password verifier type 0x939 is not supported by python-oracled in thin mode; 59192)

Pleaee help on this issue

Need to copy data from oracle db to Postgres db